# Calculating HTML input using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I am trying to calculate the percentage using the input from the HTML input

```
let timeSpend = document.querySelector(".time_spend")

var fSubject = (50/timeSpend)*100;
var sSubject = (25/timeSpend)*100;
var tSubject = (25/timeSpend)*100;
window.alert(fSubject);
```

This is my HTML input that I have the type of number but I don't know why it still not working

```
<input
          type="number"
          id="text-box"
          class="time_spend"
          placeholder="How much time do you have?"
        />
```

Comment: Elements have a value property

Comment: To get the *value* of the element, you need to use its `.value` property (or `.valueAsNumber` in your case if you like). ([More here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement).) Right now you're trying to use the element itself in the calculation, not its value. Also be sure to do the calculation in response to an event (such as a button click or a change to the input), not right away, since if you do it right away you'll be getting the starting value of the input, not the value you enter later.

Comment: And you need to get the value whenever the input is changed - not at loading time -> `.addEventListener("input",...)` ...

Answer (score 0):

When you want to get a value out of an input, you should use `.value` on the element. And when you want do to this should still be decided, do you want it on a submit or a button click. This is an example using a button.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
    <input type="number" id="text-box" class="time_spend" placeholder="How much time do you have?" />
    <button onclick="buttonClicked()">test</button>
</body>
<script>
    const buttonClicked = () => {
        let timeSpend = document.querySelector(".time_spend").value;

        console.log(timeSpend);

        var fSubject = (50 / timeSpend) * 100;
        var sSubject = (25 / timeSpend) * 100;
        var tSubject = (25 / timeSpend) * 100;
        window.alert(fSubject);
    };
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do it if you want the percentages to be recalculated when you change the value in the input.

I'm outputting the percentages in the html here just as an example

```js
const timeSpendInput = document.querySelector(".time_spend")
const fSubjectSpan = document.querySelector("#fSubject");
const sSubjectSpan = document.querySelector("#sSubject");
const tSubjectSpan = document.querySelector("#tSubject");

timeSpendInput.addEventListener("change", () => {
  const timeSpend = timeSpendInput.value;
  const fSubject = (50/timeSpend)*100;
  const sSubject = (25/timeSpend)*100;
  const tSubject = (25/timeSpend)*100;
  
  fSubjectSpan.innerHTML = fSubject;
  sSubjectSpan.innerHTML = sSubject;
  tSubjectSpan.innerHTML = tSubject;

})
```

```html
<input
          type="number"
          id="text-box"
          class="time_spend"
          placeholder="How much time do you have?"
        />
<br>
<label>fSubject: <span id="fSubject"></span></label>
<br>
<label>sSubject: <span id="sSubject"></span></label>
<br>
<label>tSubject: <span id="tSubject"></span></label>
```